# Ubuntu Server Port Forwarding the easy way?

Tags: ubuntu, nat, port-forwarding

I have an Ubuntu server (10.04) running nat and I understand how to forward ports using iptables which works fine and is only mildly painful. What is "the easy way" of doing this? Is there some nice wiz-bang-network-tool (like ufw) that **makes simple port forwarding super simple**.

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of web-based script generators that'll help you get your initial iptables rules setup for you; once you've created your base rules, it's trivial to edit and make changes afterwards.  Once you get the hang of it, you won't need (and likely won't want) a GUI anymore:

http://easyfwgen.morizot.net/gen/index.php

http://www.mista.nu/iptables/

[Firewall Builder 4.0](http://www.fwbuilder.org) (open source, Windows/Linux/Mac OSX/BSD) looks interesting and could be useful for managing large deployments and/or complex rules:
http://www.fwbuilder.org

[Shorewall](http://www.shorewall.net/)'s been around for a while too and looks promising (haven't tried it either).

Comment: +1 for shorewall, it's really good.

Answer (score 1):

check out ipkungfoo.

http://freshmeat.net/projects/ipkungfu

or ..use shorewall but with the addition of webmin.
webmins interface for shorewall is quite excellent.